# QVariant returns invalid meanwhile the value is valid

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery, qvariant

I have a small function like this

```
bool QcgDatabase::onceindb(const QString& userId)
{
    mDb->prepareSqlQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE userid=:userId;", "database");
    mDb->prepareBindValue(":userId", userId);
    mDb->sqlExec();

    bool d = mDb->sqlQuery().isActive();
    QVariant c = mDb->sqlQuery().value(QString("count(*)"));
    int e = c.toInt();

    if (e == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I do this command in SQL, the result looks like this

[image: sql]

I just want to take value `2` for comparison below, but in the code when I debug, `QVariant c` always return invalid, therefore `e is always = 0`. I thought my SQL command is not active, but when I debug, `bool d`always return true. Do you guys know why? how can I receive `2` as expected ?

Comment: `if (c == 1)` is this supposed to be `if (e == 1)`?

Comment: You should probably check for errors...

Comment: @HonestAbe: yeah, sorry, it should be `e==1`. I correct it already, Could you help me to point out problem ?

Comment: @hyde: I checked again with `bool valid = mDb->sqlQuery().isValid();` the result is `false`. But I still don't know why it is invalid. :(

Comment: You should probably read the docs of `mDb`... You want something like http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#lastError

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to fetch the result from a column with a special (and in some places invalid) name `count(*)`. You can set an alias for the column and fetch the value using that column alias:

```
...
mDb->prepareSqlQuery("SELECT count(*) as count FROM mytable WHERE userid=:userId;", "database");
...
QVariant c = mDb->sqlQuery().value("count");
...
```

And **checking return values** for error states is also good practice...